# Strict Contextual Escaping in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

We are making a api call, and in response we get a url. In Angular JS, we can trust the url by using `$sce.trustAsResourceUrl`.

So what will be the equivalent of `trustAsResourceUrl` in React JS.

In Angular,

```
//Here response is my api response
var url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(response.url);
```

The above url to use in an iframe.

Answer (score 1):

Since React doesn't bind URLs to resources like Angular can, the need for trusted resources doesn't occur.

Utilising the URL in a React app is something you do outside of the framework i.e. using `fetch`.

In essence, React doesn't manage your resources like Angular does because the resources are not bound to framework elements - unlike Angular's `ng-src`.

This is still the case when using an `iframe`. The `src` isn't bound to the component in the way that `ng-src` binds. Instead it's really just rendering the `iframe` and giving it the standard HTML attributes.